# the way/how meaning difference

Tags: meaning, word-usage

"How do you know you won't attain greatness?"

1."Exactly **the way** I know I don't have three hands. It's obvious."

"How do you know you won't attain greatness?"

2."Exactly **how** I know I don't have three hands. It's obvious."

Do both the sentences, sentence 1 and 2 convey the same meaning?
Is sentence 2 grammatically correct? Can **how** ever be used instead of **the way**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both these sentences are grammatically correct and, aside from (1) being a bit more informal, mean the same thing. As far as I know you can always replace "the way" (when used like this) with "how."

However, "the way" has a narrower meaning, so there are several contexts in which you can use "how" but not "the way." You cannot use "the way" in situations where "how" means "to what extent" rather than "in what way": *I love how beautiful you are* is fine, but *I love the way beautiful you are* is nonsense.

Naturally "the way" cannot be used in questions. *How do you get there?* cannot be *The way you get there?*

It's also less appropriate in embedded questions: *I wonder how they do that* is fine but *I wonder the way they do that* is not. However, this is only the case when what is embedded is an indirect question (usually indicated by what verb is used with it) - *I know how they do that* and *I know the way they do that* are both fine.

Answer (score 1):

**the way** in this usage is informal in register and **how** is neutral. They have the same practical meaning.